# C++/Qt - error: C2027: use of undefined type 'QBitmap'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add an image to a QLabel on a Qt creator program. However when compiling the program I get an error: `C:\Users\*****\Documents\GameAPP\main.cpp:12: error: C2027: use of undefined type 'QBitmap'`

Using Qt version 5.7 and 5.6 on Windows 10.

## This is my code:

### main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QLabel *l = new QLabel();
    QPixmap p("C:\Users\*****\Pictures\Start_Orb.png");
    l->setPixmap(p);
    l->setMask(p.mask()); //error at this line
    l->setFixedSize(20, 20);
    l->move(20, 20);
    l->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

### mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: `QPixmap p("C:\Users\*****\Pictures\Start_Orb.png");` I assume your compiler warned about the bad escape sequences. I usually just use / instead of \ even on windows.

Comment: Add #include <QBitmap> to main.cpp.

Comment: It was the backslashes, I just changed them to double backslash.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add `#include <QBitmap>` and it will work.